# WPF Binding with Dataview not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, ado.net

I am facing issue when i am creating more than one dataview for datatable then binding is not working properly for new instances. Pleae help me to sort out this....

Have anyone have solution for this issue ? Please refer below for more details

Previous Post:

"  we are experiencing the PropertyChange event on DataRowView not being raised for new Dataview instances.This appears to be an ADO bug, not WPF.  After the app creates a new DataView, WPF subscribes to change events from the DataView's only member (a DataRowView), and unsubscribes to change events from the old DataRowView.  Then somehow ADO changes the new DataView without any notification, replacing the new DataRowView with the old one.  Now changes to the Name column affect the old DataRowView, and WPF never hears about them because it's listening to the new DataRowView."

Thanks in advance..

## Code :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfStudy.GridView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfStudy"
         Height="400" Width="500" Title="Binding Listview with Mulit ItemSource Options">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:NameConverter  x:Key="NameConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel>
            <Button Click="Button_Click">Click</Button>
            <ListView Name="ListviewALL" >
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Binding Label" >
                            <GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource NameConverter}">
                                    <Binding  Path="LastName" />
                                    <Binding  Path="FirstName" />
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
                        </GridViewColumn>

                        <GridViewColumn Width="140">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBox Name="FirstName" FontFamily="Lucida Console" Text="{Binding FirstName,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="200" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="140">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBox Name="LastName" FontFamily="Lucida Console" Text="{Binding LastName,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="200" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>


                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>

        </StackPanel>
        <ListView Name="Listview" Grid.Row="1">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Binding Label" >
                        <GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource NameConverter}">
                                <Binding  Path="LastName" />
                                <Binding  Path="FirstName" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                    <GridViewColumn Width="140">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Name="FirstName" FontFamily="Lucida Console" Text="{Binding FirstName,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="200" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="140">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Name="LastName" FontFamily="Lucida Console" Text="{Binding LastName,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="200" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>


                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>

        <ListView Name="Listview1" Grid.Row="2">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Binding Label" >
                        <GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource NameConverter}">
                                <Binding  Path="LastName" />
                                <Binding  Path="FirstName" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                    <GridViewColumn Width="140">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Name="FirstName" FontFamily="Lucida Console" Text="{Binding FirstName,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="200" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="140">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Name="LastName" FontFamily="Lucida Console" Text="{Binding LastName,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="200" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>


                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>



    </Grid>
</Window>
```

## Converter :

```
namespace WpfStudy
{
    public class NameConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {

            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

            foreach(string val in values)
            {

                if (sb.Length != 0)
                    sb.Append(" ");

                    sb.Append(val);

            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

}
```

## Binding Source

```
- i am binding datatable source with 3 list view with differnet dataview. if we create more view instance then two way binding is not working.xaml not getting updated from source.

  private void loadDatatable()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("FirstName");
            dt.Columns.Add("LastName");
            dt.Columns.Add("Userid");


            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "Siva";
            dr[1] = "Jagan";
            dr[2] = "JS";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
            dr1[0] = "Raam";
            dr1[1] = "John";
            dr1[2] = "RJ";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr1);


            ListviewALL.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

            dv1 = new DataView(dt);
            dv1.RowFilter = "FirstName like'S%'";


            dv2 = new DataView(dt);
            dv2.RowFilter = "FirstName like 'R%'";


            Listview.ItemsSource = dv1;
            Listview1.ItemsSource = dv2;

        }
```

Comment: Please post code and describe what happens.

Comment: yep, where's the code...

Comment: I have added code part.please let me know if you require more details

Comment: Binding to a `DataTable` is not really elegant. You should be binding to a custom class with public properties that model your data.

Comment: But my existing code model using datatable only.i cant change that pattern.

Comment: added a working sample to my answer

Answer (score 1):

what happens when you take a BindingListCollectionView or ICollectionView instead of the Dataview to filter your stuff?

EDIT:

i tried it out and the following works:

```
    public BindingListCollectionView View1 { get; set; }
    public BindingListCollectionView View2 { get; set; }

    View1 = new BindingListCollectionView(new DataView(Dt) { RowFilter = "FirstName like 'R%'" });
    View2 = new BindingListCollectionView(new DataView(Dt) { RowFilter = "FirstName like 'S%'"});
```

Add, Modify and Delete works.

EDIT2 my sample code: update to fullfill your requirements. editing through the textbox in any listview works!

```
public class Viewmodel
{
    public DataTable Dt { get; set; }
    public BindingListCollectionView View1 { get; set; }
    public BindingListCollectionView View2 { get; set; }

    public Viewmodel()
    {
        Dt = new DataTable();
        Dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        Dt.Columns.Add("VorName");


        DataRow dr = Dt.NewRow();
        dr[0] = "Siva";
        dr[1] = "Jagan";
        Dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        DataRow dr1 = Dt.NewRow();
        dr1[0] = "Raam";
        dr1[1] = "John";
        Dt.Rows.Add(dr1);


        View1 = new BindingListCollectionView(new DataView(Dt) { RowFilter = "Name like 'R%'" });
        View2 = new BindingListCollectionView(new DataView(Dt){RowFilter = "Name like 'S%'"});

    }
}
```

window.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Viewmodel _data;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this._data = new Viewmodel();

        this.DataContext = _data;
    }
}
```

window.xaml

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <local:NameConverter  x:Key="NameConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="138*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="209*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="156*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="76*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="235*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>     
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Dt}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Binding Label" >
                    <GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource NameConverter}">
                            <Binding  Path="Name" />
                            <Binding  Path="VorName" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" > 
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Name="FirstName" FontFamily="Lucida Console" Text="{Binding Name,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="200" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>    
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="VorName" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding VorName}">
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding View1}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Binding Label" >
                    <GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource NameConverter}">
                            <Binding  Path="Name" />
                            <Binding  Path="VorName" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name"  > 
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Name="FirstName" FontFamily="Lucida Console" Text="{Binding Name,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="200" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate> 
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="VorName" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding VorName}">
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding View2}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Binding Label" >
                    <GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource NameConverter}">
                            <Binding  Path="Name" />
                            <Binding  Path="VorName" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </GridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding>
                </GridViewColumn>

                <GridViewColumn Header="Name"  > 
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Name="FirstName" FontFamily="Lucida Console" Text="{Binding Name,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="200" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate> 

                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="VorName" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding VorName}">

                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Check wheather "Binding Label" column values reflecting when you are changes either first name or last name in second and third list view.

Comment: as long as i edit the underlying datatable rows, all changes are reflected for all 3 Listviews. so its working for me.

Comment: its not working. i am expecting result as i am binding same dt column to two list view column.if you edit any one of column value it should reflect in another column. this is working fine with single view instance.but when you go for more dataview instance then auto binding not working properly

Comment: if got three listview with one datatable an three different views/filters. and if i change a a value in the datatable row, the changes are reflected in all 3 views/listviews. how do you edit your datatable? i just did something like this for testing Dt.Rows[0][1] = "Test1";

Comment: dont try to edit any thing in code.try with xaml itself.please try recreate with my code.that will give more understanding about my issue.

Comment: i added your textbox datatemplate for the column and still see all changes even if i change the value in the textbox of the listview.

Comment: added my sample project here: http://blindmeis.wordpress.com/2012/04/20/wpf-datatable-and-multiple-views/

Answer (score 0):

Try this after each addition ...

```
  dt.AcceptChanges();
```

And if that doesnt work then reset the row filter

```
  var tempFilter = dt.DefaultView.RowFilter;
  dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.empty;
  dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = tempFilter;
```

Comment: Did you try setting the filter with equality .. something like ... `"FirstName = 'Siva'"`? Does it still not show data?

Comment: can i get any solution for this issue?